# Grid layout doesn't work properly on API level 19?

Tags: android, user-interface, grid-layout

I am facing a problem and I have searched a lot about it but couldn't find a solution.

I used a grid layout in my design and it works fine with API level > 19, but when I run my App on API level 19 it doesn't work properly:

**Here is a screenshot of my App running on API level > 19:** 
[Screenshot (when API level > 19)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNB9H.png)

**And on API level 19:** 
[Screenshot (when API = 19)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVPe3.png)

I tried adding these lines to the gradle file but they didn't help:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:28.0.0'
```

And here is my layout.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/bg"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".ui.home.HomeActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/azkar_logo" />

    <GridLayout
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
        android:columnOrderPreserved="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="8"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <!-- Row 1 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:onClick="startSalah"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/praying"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="90dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="@string/salah"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:onClick="startQuran"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/quran" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="@string/quran"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <!-- Row 2 -->
        <!-- Column 1 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <ImageView
                    android:onClick="startSonan"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:src="@drawable/sonan"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="90dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="@string/sonan"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <!-- Column 2 -->
        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_columnWeight="1"
            android:layout_rowWeight="1"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            app:cardElevation="8dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <ImageView
                    android:onClick="startSadaqa"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="90dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:scaleType="centerInside"
                    android:src="@drawable/sadaqah" />

                <TextView
                    android:textAlignment="center"
                    android:text="@string/sadaqah"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
                    android:textSize="18sp"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    </GridLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_main_score"
            android:onClick="showPoints"
            android:text="@string/score"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView is really outdated.
You need to use `RecyclerView` with `GridLayoutManager` instead.

Here is a simple example as how to use it:

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, numberOfColumns));
```

Comment: i will try it now

Comment: thanks i was tring to make it manually but it didint work. your solution solve it
Thanks